# How to replace multiple lines in file in Python using sed

Tags: python, sed, replace

I'm trying to quickly replace the entire line in a file (titled filename) that starts with the string 'NATOMS' with multiple lines. I am trying to do this using os.system, but nothing is happening. If I copy this string into the command line, it works. Here is the code:

```
import os
os.system("sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye' filename")
```

The error I receive (Python 2.7) is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: extra characters after command
```

I want to replace this entire line (the numbers change from file to file) in filename:

```
NATOMS     6   -1.10
```

with

```
NATOMS     5   -1.10
 hi
bye
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: If you are going to use `python` why not just use the `re` module?

Comment: You're using Python. Not sed. Use Python (re) for your task: it will be much more elegant, and much more portable (and likely faster too).

Comment: If you are not comfortable or having trouble understanding `re`, just open the file in `python` and read the file line by line.

Comment: You say "I am trying to do this using os.system". Why, exactly, are you trying to do it using `os.system`? Would you be comfortable with a pure python answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a raw string to prevent python from parsing the input string before passing it on the OS call.

The below example illustrates this

Your input string is

```
sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye' sedinp.txt
```

Now assign it to a variable and print it

```
>>> normalcmd="sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye' sedinp.txt"
>>> print normalcmd
sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10
 hi
bye' sedinp.txt
>>>
```

As you see, the escape sequences have been parsed.

Now create a raw string.

```
>>> rawcmd=r"sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye' sedinp.txt"
>>> print rawcmd
sed -i -e '/NATOMS/c\NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye' sedinp.txt
>>>
```

You can see that the escape sequences are not parsed.

Now use it in the os call.

```
>>> os.system(rawcmd)
0
>>>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward ***Python*** way:

```
with open('yourfilename', 'r+') as f:
    repl_str = 'NATOMS     5   -1.10\n hi\nbye'
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for l in lines:
        f.write(repl_str if l.startswith('NATOMS') else l)
```